# mysql select n rows before and n rows after

Tags: php, mysql, union

I am trying to create a mysql query to select let's say 5 rows before and 5 rows depending on the currend ID. Here is the query I am trying to use:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE PID<='10' ORDER BY PID DESC LIMIT 7
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE PID>'10' ORDER BY PID ASC LIMIT 6
```

For some reason though, the query is not working. Am I missing something? I found this solution in a forum post.

Comment: You need to wrap those up in parentheses if you're going to do it that way - and I guess the first one needs an alias too.

Comment: Are the PIDs consecutive? Then precalculate the range and just have one `WHERE pid BETWEEN (10-5) AND (10+5)` clause.

Comment: what is not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(SELECT *
 FROM posts
 WHERE PID <= '10'
 ORDER BY PID DESC LIMIT 7
 )
UNION ALL
(SELECT *
 FROM posts
 WHERE PID > '10'
 ORDER BY PID ASC LIMIT 6
 )
ORDER BY PID ASC;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b214d/4)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

The `PID` is likely of ***int*** type.  So you should be using the following (<kbd>[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01dfb/2/0)</kbd>):

```
(SELECT * FROM posts WHERE PID <= 10 ORDER BY PID DESC LIMIT 7)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM posts WHERE PID > 10 ORDER BY PID ASC LIMIT 6)
```

As you can see the ordering of the two queries is also maintained separately.

Answer (score 0):

[DOCS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

> To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT: